# ufw on rPi with OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, raspberry-pi, ufw

I've setup OpenVPN using the piVPN method on a raspberry pi.
The installation has gone fine, I've configured the port forwarding on my router and I can connect successfully to the VPN from my android device.

The problem I'm having though is that if I reboot the rPi, then I can't connect to the VPN.
To successfully connect I have to disable ufw.
In actual fact, I can disable it and then immediately re-enable it, and I can then connect from my android device.

To replicate, I reboot the rPi.
At that point, I can't connect to the VPN.
via SSH, i then run `sudo ufw disable` followed immediately by `sudo ufw enable`. I can then connect successfully to the VPN.
Just running `sudo ufw enable` or even `sudo ufw --force enable` is not enough to make this work. It's essential to first disable `ufw` and then re-enable it.

Immediately after a reboot, before disabling/re-enabling ufw, I've used `netcat` from another machine to see if I can connect to `UDP port 1194`. The connection is successful, which suggests that the port is open.

I can only think that something else is being enabled or disabled at the time I disabled ufw.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be happening here or how I can troubleshoot where the issues are?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but has got my setup into a workable state.

If I disable `UFW` and reboot then it should be disabled when the system restarts.
At that point, running `sudo ufw status` generates an error `problem running ip6tables`

I haven't yet worked why that is or how to properly resolve it, but disabling and then enabling `UFW` does sort it out.

I've therefore added code to disable and then enable it into `/etc/rc.local`